# Rails Active Record, get related record from has_many :through relationship with where clause on through record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a relationship set up with a `has_many :through`.

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient

  # physician_id, patient_id
end


class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

How can I get all patients for a given physician where the appointment's role is equal to PI or G2?

I've tried `Physician.find(50).appointments.where('role = ? or role = ?', 'PI', 'G2').patients`

Edit:

I'm getting undefined method from the above.  Shouldn't I be able to get the through's related records?  In `Physician.find(50).appointments.where('role = ? or role = ?', 'PI', 'G2')` there should be an `appointments` method but there is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want Patient objects back, start with that model. You want to add WHERE clauses on both Appointments and Physicians, so join on those associations. Use the Hash form of `where` to reference the joined tables.

```
Patient.joins(:physician).
  joins(:appointments).
  where(appointments: {role: ["PI", "G2"]}).
  where(physicians: {id: physician_id}).uniq
```

**Update**

Consider adding scopes to your models that you can reuse:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_physician, ->(physician_id) do
    joins(:physicians).
    where(physicians: {id: physician_id}
  end

  scope :for_roles, ->(roles) do
    joins(:appointments).
    merge(Appointment.for_roles(roles))
  end
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_roles, ->(roles) do
    where(role: roles)
  end
end
```

Then you can put them together like this

```
Patient.for_physician(50).for_roles(["PI", "G2"]).uniq
```